# how to make the browser wait for assets to load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

I am loading scripts and style-sheets dynamically from javascript like [this](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html).

The problem is that browser does not wait for the script to load.

consider i have a function named **functionToBeCalled()** inside a script file named **script-file.js**

i have a function to load script file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var listOfJavaScriptsLoaded = new Array();

    function LoadScriptFile(scriptUrl){
      var isScriptLoaded = false;
      var i = 0;
      for(i = 0; i < listOfJavaScriptsLoaded.length; i ++){
        if(listOfJavaScriptsLoaded[i] == scriptUrl){
           isScriptLoaded = true;
           break;
         }  
      } 
    if(isScriptLoaded == false){        
     var headTag= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];      
     var scriptTag= document.createElement('script');
     scriptTag.type= 'text/javascript';
     scriptTag.src= scriptUrl;
     headTag.appendChild(scriptTag);
     listOfJavaScriptsLoaded.push(scriptUrl);
    }
    }
   LoadScriptFile("script-file.js");
   functionToBeCalled();
</script>
```

now, what happens is that the browser does not wait for the script tag to load and goes to the next command. I get a "**undefined functionToBeCalled()**" error. this is natural. But the fact is that when i inspect in firebug, the script tag has been formed and the file has loaded.

So how do i make the browser to pause loading and resume after the asset has been loaded?

**Edit1:** This problem occurs only when i am loading the page in ajax and not in normal page loads

**Edit2:** Or is there a possibility to read a script/css file from javascript and write it directly in the markup within script tags

If i use **window.stop()** the loading stops completely. how can i make it resume from the same line?

Or is it possible to make the browser to consider that the loading is still happening and reset it in the onload event?

Comment: Why load them this way in the first place? Is it absolutely not an option to put them directly into the head tag, or write out `<script>` tags? It would be much simpler.

Comment: @pekka:it doesn't make a difference as to where i append the script tag to if that is what you were pointing

Comment: @ZX122R it does. If you write it out as a normal `<script src='...'>` tag in the body, loading of the page will wait until the script has been loaded

Comment: Listen to Pekka, for he is wise.

Comment: @pekka: tried it.. doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: @ZX12 it should. Can you show some code?

Comment: have edited to include my inclusion code. kindly check if i am missing somethig

Comment: @ZX12R no, I mean get rid of the dynamic JS loading altogether and do a `<script src="script-file.js"></script>`. I made my answer more verbose to outline  this

Comment: @pekka: sorry i misunderstood. But i keep an array of loaded scripts and not load a script that has been loaded already. how do i implement this?

Comment: @ZX totally depends on your server-side language and flow control, impossible to answer without details. That may be material for a new question

Comment: i have edited the code again.. kindly check

Answer (score 3):

You may have specific reasons to load the script dynamically, but to present the option, if you write out the script element in your HTML output like so:

```
<script src="script-file.js"></script>
<script>functionToBeCalled();</script>
```

the browser will halt parsing until that script has been loaded, and interpreted.

This is also valid [in the BODY](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1).

Answer (score 2):

Check out LABjs ( http://labjs.com/ ) by Getify Solutions. LABjs allows script-inserted scripts to be loaded concurrently but run in order.

Comment: doesn't this fail with jQuery?

Comment: According to the labjs documentation, there's something of an incompatibiity with jQuery 1.3 but not with 1.4

Comment: looks like a very good option except for the fact that many of the plugins i use have not yet started support for 1.4 yet..:(

Answer (score 0):

pretty much every tag which loads a resource has an onload event. so in plain javascript this means in your case something like this:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = "script-file.js";
s.type = 'text/javascript';
head.appendChild(s);

s.onload = function(){
    functionToBeCalled();
}
```

Comment: how do i tell the browser to resume loading other elements in onload event?

Comment: @ZX12R that will happen automatically. However, IE doesn't seem to support `onload` for script elements. See here for a workaround: http://blog.andrewcantino.com/post/211671748/replacement-for-script-onload-in-ie

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at [Cuzillion](http://stevesouders.com/cuzillion/).  It will allow you to experiment with calling [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [css](/questions/tagged/css) in many different ways to see how they react in the browser.

This should answer your question.  Just execute it before your page is done loading the `body`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var loadScriptFile = (function(){
        var listOfJavaScriptsLoaded = [];

        return function(scriptUrl){
            var isScriptLoaded = false;
            for(var i = 0; i < listOfJavaScriptsLoaded.length; i ++){
                if(listOfJavaScriptsLoaded[i] == scriptUrl){
                    isScriptLoaded = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!isScriptLoaded){
                document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="' + scriptUrl + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
            }
        };
    }());
    loadScriptFile("script-file.js");
    functionToBeCalled();
</script>
```